# In grails, what is the quickest way to obtain a reference to the current hibernate session?

Tags: hibernate, spring, grails, spring-mvc

I got a singleton service and inside its only method I need to obtain a reference to the hibernate session bound to the current request. What is the quickest way of doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We do it the following way:

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class YourService  {

    SessionFactory sessionFactory // set by Dependency Injection

    public void yourMethod() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        // do something with session
    }
}
```

When your service is in the grails-app/services directory and ends wirh "Service", the sessionFactory is injected by grails.

Comment: is sessionFactory.getCurrentSession thread safe?  Im wondering since he is trying to access it from a static utility method.

Comment: @hvgotcodes, take look at this - http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Hibernate/3.2.4.sp01.cp03/api/hibernate-core/org/hibernate/context/CurrentSessionContext.html

Comment: @Olexandr: that link is dead. Could you add a quick pointer what it was about? Maybe the fact that the Session does not need to be thread-safe?

Comment: Docs says that "Implementors must be threadsafe." - [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) And talking about Grails - it has static application context, which contains sessionFactory which makes me believe that it should be thread safe because of possible errors. And the last argument - SessionFactory is immutable so it's state is persistant and that's why almost no thread problems could occur.

Answer (score 3):

Or just

```
def someServiceMethod {
   SomeDomainObjectClass.withSession { session ->
     .....
   }
}
```

Domain objects are classes defined in grails-app/domain directory.
`session` variable will obtain current Hibernate Session reference inside `withSession` closure.